# How can Cell delete for UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, cell

I have most `IBOutlet` on `TableView Cell`
They cover cell `swipe` Left Action.
Cell only a small amount of space trigger delete Action.
Place Help me
How can add SwipeGestureRecognizer in IBOutlet on cell

Comment: You should try to explain better your problem, and give some code. Here it's not understandable.

Comment: You bring almost no information in your question.

Comment: Everybody I'm Sorry, I know question.
This question is I Have use MFSideMenu.
MFSideMenu I use right .But cell delete is Left.
They is different. But I close MFSideMenu is OK!
So in -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated  use MFSideMenuPanModeSideMenu is OK.
Very much Thanks for Everybody.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, add this:

```
   - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
return YES;
}
```

Then

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    //remove the deleted object from your data source.
    //If your data source is an NSMutableArray, do this
    [self.dataArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView reloadData]; // tell table to refresh now
  }
}
```

Comment: This I know , But I have Object IB in Cell . So I Can't Swipe Left show delete.I need add Gesture Recognizer in Object IB

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
       NSString   *str  = @"are you sure you want to delete";
    UIAlertView *logoutAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:str delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes",nil];
    [logoutAlert setTag:indexPath.row];
    [logoutAlert show];
    }
}
```

in alertview delegate method if u have only one section

```
    -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

        if(buttonIndex == 1)
        {
               [tblView beginUpdates];
                [tblView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:alertView.tag inSection:0], nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
                [tblView endUpdates];
                [tblView reloadData];   
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is may not be your required answer, but please try once.

This code is for, suppose you are adding `UITextField`, `UIButton`, `UILabel` etc on cell. This method is detect only gesture recognizer on cell.

```
 - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
   if ([touch.view isDescendantOfView:yourLabel] ||[touch.view isDescendantOfView:yourTextview] || [touch.view isDescendantOfView:yourButton])
   {
       return NO;
   }
   return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add scrollview in your custom cell on swip use these method to delete.(i used for left swip to hide and delete here). set scrollView on full cell and IB in it.

```
 - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

        [self.scrollViewCell setContentSize:CGSizeMake(640.0f, self.scrollViewCell.contentSize.height)];
        [self.scrollViewCell setExclusiveTouch:YES];

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    -(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

        float opacity = ( 180 - scrollView.contentOffset.x ) / 100.0;
        opacity = (opacity < 0? 0.2f : opacity>1? 1 : opacity);
        scrollView.layer.opacity = opacity;
    }
    -(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
        int pageNum = (int)(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width);
        if(pageNum==1){
            [_delegate deleteTableViewCellAtRow:scrollView.tag];
        }
    }
```

Here delegate is your tableview controller.